# Python Tkinter Rotate Window, turn to the right

Tags: python, linux, rotation, tkinter

Someone has written a really simple "paint" program in Python and I want to modify it a little bit. Some my question is. How can implement a rotate function to this program? I want to be able to rotate the window that the program is represented in 90 degrees to the right. Is this possible? Would it also be possible to implement a function to remove the border from the window. (It's the gui window I'm talking about).

```
from Tkinter import *

"""paint.py: not exactly a paint program.. just a smooth line drawing demo."""

b1 = "up"
xold, yold = None, None

def main():
    root = Tk()
    drawing_area = Canvas(root)
    drawing_area.pack()
    drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", motion)
    drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", b1down)
    drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", b1up)
    root.mainloop()

def b1down(event):
    global b1
    b1 = "down"           # you only want to draw when the button is down
                          # because "Motion" events happen -all the time-

def b1up(event):
    global b1, xold, yold
    b1 = "up"
    xold = None           # reset the line when you let go of the button
    yold = None

def motion(event):
    if b1 == "down":
        global xold, yold
        if xold is not None and yold is not None:
            event.widget.create_line(xold,yold,event.x,event.y,smooth=TRUE)
                          # here's where you draw it. smooth. neat.
        xold = event.x
        yold = event.y

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to just rotate the screen in Linux. I managed to do this with the command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate right
```

Answer (score 1):

'Rotating' your screen, so that a different edge of the screen is treated as the top edge, is something that the operating system has to do.  For instance, on Win 7, right click on screen, select Resolution, then select Orientation.  The choices are Landscape (normal), Portrait (left edge, starting from Landscape) is top), Inverted Landscape, and Inverted Portrait.  This works even if screen is *not* physically rotated -- but is a bit weird since cursor movement assumes that the screen *is* rotated.

Comment: Are you sure this is not possible in Linux? It's possible to just rotate windows for several programs in Linux. One example is mplayer, if you start the program with `mplayer rotate=1` from the terminal the whole window will turn 90 degrees to the right and everything else in the OS stay the same.

Comment: Hmmm. What I *am* sure of is that the current tkinter chapter in the library manual does not contain 'rotate' and that the function - signature page produced by pydoc only contains 'rotate' as a parameter of the Canvas.postscript.  So I am rather sure that tkinter cannot independently rotate one of its windows.

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly do you want to rotate the window? is it just because of the geometry? if so you could just resize the canvas to give the appearance of having been rotated using width and height arguments when it is created (or using configure on it after its been created)

and to remove the border (and the titlebar with it) you can use:

```
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

in your `main()`

Comment: It's because I try do develop a simple paint program for a Kiosk. The screen on the kiosk is turned 90 degrees so the program must turn with it. It's a good solution to remove the border (I was planning to do this too), but there's one obstacle with it.
If I have something like this `menubar.add_command(label="Reset Image", command=restart_program)` it will appear on the left side and is not "rotated" with the window.

Comment: Seems like I could change this with a `anchor` option.

Comment: ah ok, i see what you mean, have you looked at the documentation for your linux distro to see if there is an option to rotate the whole screen output? it is a common feature on a lot of graphics cards, and some OS's do feature built in support for this too, it does seem like that might be the easiest option however i am guessing you're using a touch screen? so no idea what that would do, i think it would need to be reconfigured to match..

Comment: failing that (i know how much of a headache this is) but you may have to implement your own menu method to do it

Comment: I succeed to turn the screen in the OS instead. But I kinda solved it with the menu by creating buttons instead and changing coordinates instead. But I wont be needing that. :)
The command for the screen to turn 90 degrees to the right was `xrandr --output HDMI1 --rotate right`. And since this is Kiosk with touch I also had to rotate the touch, `xinput set-prop 'Advanced Silicon S.A CoolTouch(TM) System' 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1`